# Dynamic import in react not working when trying to import a component in another directory

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-import

Hello everyone I have been trying dynamic imports in react for rendering my components for an app created with CRA (create-react-app) and while it works perfectly for some cases but for some it returns a cannot load module error for instance I loaded a component(placed in a directory under src) dynamically in  my `index.js` which works fine but when I try to render a child or nested component inside that also with a dynamic import approach it gives error cannot load module. Note this error occurs only if the nested component is placed outside the directory of the original parent component enough talk here is the code.

My index.js  placed under src.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';

    class Dynamic extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { module: null };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
          console.log('in comp mount')
          //alert("in comp mount")
        const { path } = this.props;
        import(`${path}`)
          .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
     }
      render() {
          console.log('in render')
         // alert("in render")
        const { module: Component } = this.state; // Assigning to new variable names @see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
        return(
          <div>
            {Component && <Component path= '../FooterComp/Footer' />}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Dynamic path='./Components/FirstComponent' />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

FirstComponent.js  placed in Components directory under src.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import '../FirstApp.css';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { module: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      console.log('in comp mount')
      //alert("in comp mount")
    const { path } = this.props;
    alert(path)
    import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
 }

  render() {
      const { module: Component } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
        {Component && <Component />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Footer.js   placed in FooterComp directory under src.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class Footer extends Component {
    componentDidMount()
    {
        console.log('in componentDidMount of Footer')
    }
  render() {
      console.log('in render of Footer')
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Edited by Me</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

Why does this work when I refer my firstcomponent from my `index.js` but doesnt work for footer component when trying to import in my firstcomponent?

Errormessage: `Error: Cannot find module '../FooterComp/Footer'`

Also note that if i place Footer component in the same directory as Firstcomponent and adjust the path it works fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There’s limitation when using dynamic imports with variable parts.

[Webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

> It is not possible to use a fully dynamic import statement, such as import(foo). Because foo could potentially be any path to any file in your system or project.

> The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located. Bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files so that when you are using a dynamic expression - every module that could potentially be requested on an import() call is included.For example, import(`./locale/${language}.json`) will cause every .json file in the ./locale directory to be bundled into the new chunk. At run time, when the variable language has been computed, any file like english.json or german.json will be available for consumption.

In your case, during build time for dynamic import in `FirstComponent` component, bundling was limited to directory where the `FirstComponent` component was i.e. `Components` directory.

What it means is that, webpack will find all the files that are in the `Components` directory and then create [chunks](https://webpack.js.org/glossary/) for them. Then at runtime when dynamic import is called, webpack will serve the chunk that corresponds to the value passed in.

Since you passed `path= '../FooterComp/Footer'` has no corresponding chunk so webpack will throw the error.

This is also same for `Dynamic` component. If you try to dynamically import with variable parts for the files that are outside `src` folder, you will get same error.

So to solve this you have couple of options

1. place both files in same folder

i.e

```
'src/Components/FirstComponent.js'

'src/Components/Footer.js'
```

And use

```
// In FirstComponent.js
   componentDidMount() {
      const { path } = this.props;
      import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))   
   }


{Component && <Component path='./Footer' />} // Index.js
```

2. be more specific as possible

i.e

```
// In FirstComponent.js
 componentDidMount() {
      const { path } = this.props;
      import(`../FooterComp/${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))   
 }
```

And use

```
{Component && <Component path='Footer' />} //  In index.js
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd approach works fine but can you please provide some links or documentation which refer to the limitation you have pointed out so i can get my head around it more clearly and dont forget to upvote the question:)

Answer (score 0):

If FooterComp is under src, the path should be `'./FooterComp/Footer'` not `'../FooterComp/Footer'`

---

**Edit**

Index.js

```
    render() {
          console.log('in render')
         // alert("in render")
        const { module: Component } = this.state; 
        return(
          <div>
            {Component && <Component path='./Components/FirstComponent' />}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Dynamic />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

FirstComponent.js

```
render() {
      const { module: Component } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
        {Component && <Component path= '../FooterComp/Footer' />}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: no you see the FirstComponent is in a directory Components under src and from that i am importing a footer component that is placed under FooterComp directory so i guess i need to provide path ../FooterComp/Footer.

Comment: The error comes because it is checking the file location from the index.js file.

Comment: no it is passing the path as props to the first component and the module will be imported when FirstComponent is rendered and therefore the path to refer to footer from firstComponent i the one i have provided

Comment: Try what I edited above. I changed both paths on index.js and added a path on FirstComponent.js.