# How can I list source folder contents in React or create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm writing a React app using `create-react-app`.

Since I can do:

```
import LocalClass from "./localfolder/LocalClass.js"
```

and even (using [dynamic import](https://tc39.es/proposal-dynamic-import/#sec-import-calls)):

```
import('./localfolder/LocalClass.js').then((module) => { /* ... */ })
```

is there a way to list `localfolder` contents, so I can dynamically import the contained files?

The listing should happen at compile or bundling time, not at runtime (I'm thinking about an automatic menu creation feature).

The folder may contain plain classes too (i.e. not React components); I guess this is a matter of the bundler, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since CRA uses Webpack under the hood, you could use [`require.context()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext) to enumerate all loadable modules in a given path.

Comment: Interesting. I put together some [experimental code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60710524/3127111), though I hit a roadblock on `dynamic imports`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's kind of open-based, after some investigation

I found a lib: [react-dynamic-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dynamic-import#advanced-usage)

Usage:

```
const loader = f => import(`./dynamic/${f}.js`);
```

```
|_ dynamic
|  |_ realComponent-en.js
|  |_ realComponent-eu.js
|  |_ realComponent-kn.js
|_ container.js <-- working file
```

---

Refer:

- react document [code-splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting)
- related [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254553/dynamic-import-in-react-not-working-when-trying-to-import-a-component-in-another)

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a look. I may have non-React classes though - I'll edit the question.

Comment: @watery you can use `regex` for the `filename` based filter for the `bundler`. And feel free to leave your feedback if you have further problems using the method mentioned above.

Comment: Did that post solved your problem? Kindly inform me if you have further questions about it.

Comment: Actually, I'm experimenting with [AXK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60692680/3127111).

Comment: @watery Is this post still helpful for you? I'm cleaning my zero posts, trying to find out whether to remove this one or not

Comment: Well, I think it's too early to tell, but maybe this could anyway be useful to others.