# Can I generate source code during webpack processing / bundling?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-generation

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60692552/3127111) I got a way to dynamically scan source folders using WebPack API, and I've written [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60710524/3127111) that loads each found class using dynamic imports.

But there's nothing really dynamic here, since source files will be fixed once bundled; so the above code could then be replace with one that statically imports each discovered class.

Is there a way to generate source code during webpack execution and add it to the bundling process?

Whether possible the code should be part of the application, not a separate plugin or anything.