# How to import function from dynamically named directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi I am building next js app where I have folder structure like
pages
[state_name]
[city_name].js

I have added one method inside [city_name].js file,how can I import that method as I tried

```
import {setState} from '../[state_name]/[city_name]'
```

but it is giving error saying
Module not found: Can't resolve '../[state_name]/[city_name]'
Can anyone tell me how can I import this method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 variable import name in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js)

Comment: You can't. The ECMAScript `import` statement requires the use of string-literals, therefore module imports cannot be determined at runtime. But if this is code that will run inside NodeJS (rather than in a browser) you may be able to use `require()`.

Comment: Instead of importing from "../[state_name]/[city_name]" you can add a util file and import it from there.

Comment: Try using the approach mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257036/6333527