# Load function from external script using @loadable/component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, loadable-component

I have a JSON file with several filepaths to scripts that I want to be able to load dynamically into my React app, to build each component based on specifications that are in the metadata. Currently I have the metadata in my app as a `Metadata` data object.

metadata.json:

```
{
  "component1": { "script": "./createFirstLayer.js" },
  "component2": { "script": "./createSecondLayer.js" }
}
```

Each script exports a function that I want to be able to use to construct the component. For troubleshooting purposes, it currently only returns a simple message.

```js
function createFirstLayer(name) {
  return name + " loaded!";
}

export default createFirstLayer;
```

I did some research and identified the @loadable/component package. Using this package as `import loadable from "@loadable/component";`, I attempted to load my script into App.js like this:

```js
  async componentDidMount() {
    Object.keys(Metadata).forEach(function(name) {
      console.log(Metadata[name].script);
      var createLayer = loadable(() => import(Metadata[name].script));
      var message = createLayer(name);
      console.log(message);
    });
  }
```

Everything I have tried throws the TypeError `createLayer is not a function`. How can I get the function loaded?

I have also attempted the [lazy](https://loadable-components.com/docs/suspense/) method.

I have recreated a working demo of my problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-butterfly-zhqy4?file=/src/App.js).

EDIT: I have tried to put this at the top of my app

```
const scripts = {};
Object.keys(Metadata).forEach(async function(name) {
    import(Metadata[name].script).then((cb) => scripts[name] = cb);
});
```

This causes the TypeError Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './createFirstLayer.js'. (anonymous function)
src/components lazy /^.*$/ groupOptions: {} namespace object:66

I have also attempted

```
const scripts = {};
Object.keys(Metadata).forEach(async function(name) {
    React.lazy(() => import(Metadata[name].script).then((cb) => scripts[name] = cb));
});
```

My goal is to be able to call the appropriate function to create particular layer, and match them up in the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `@loadable/component` for two reasons.

1. You can accomplish your goal with dynamic imports
2. '@loadable/component' returns a React Component object, not your function.

To use dynamic imports simply parse your JSON the way you were, but push the call to the import's default function into `state`. Then all you have to do is render the "*layers*" from within the state.

Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Metadata from "./metadata.json";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { messages: [] };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    Object.keys(Metadata).forEach(name=> import(`${Metadata[name].script}`).then(cb =>
      this.setState((state, props) => ({ messages: [...state.messages, cb.default(cb.default.name)] }))));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.messages.map((m, idx) => (
          <h1 key={idx}>{m}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is [the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-leakey-58jp4?file=/src/App.js:125-459)

Comment: thanks! I'm looking at this more closely, since I can't seem to get the message to print inside the componentDidMount

Comment: Yeah - there is a race condition. This does work, let me fix it. But I'm going to hide this answer until is works properly.

Comment: I updated my question with an attempt that I used based on your answer

Comment: That's odd...I'll take a look in a read IDE instead of the repl stuff.

Comment: OK, here is the entire solution that renders the layers into the view. Had to move the parsing back to `componentDidMount()` to over come the race condition. Note too, that I had to use template literal string for the variable component name. But this works as expected now. Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: It does work in the sandbox! Any idea why I'm getting locally this error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module './createFirstLayer.js'
(anonymous function)
src/components lazy /^.*$/ groupOptions: {} namespace object:66

Comment: I cannot replicate that error. Are you sure you have used this: ``${Metadata[name].script}`` ?

Comment: Yes. this might be a separate problem. :( It works in codesandbox and I have the same requirements in my environment. I'm using create-react-app

Comment: aha fixed the path with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257036/4237080

Comment: Yes, that is what my comment meant. Glad you got it sorted.